# react-select-picker - Cannot open selectpicker on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-select

As my title says, I can't open the select when I click on it to display options.

Here's the relevant code. If you need more, just ask:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/theme.css';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/datepicker.css';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/core';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker';
// My own components
import StartMultiple from './Start.multiple.js';
import "bootstrap";
import SelectPicker from "react-select-picker";

render()
{
   return(
    <SelectPicker>
        <option>person</option>
    </SelectPicker>
   )
}
```

Comment: Any there any JS errors in the console?

Comment: @Jacob Not for that no, I just have some weird isURLSameOrigin error stuff that isn't messing up anything.